# error in oracle pl/sql: group function is not allowed here

Tags: oracle, plsql

--table st (sid int, sname varchar2(10), total int, grade varchar(2))

My piece of code is the following.

```
declare
totsum number;
average number;
procedure sumavg(x out number, y out number) is
begin
select sum(total) into x, avg(total) into y from st;
end;

begin
sumavg(totsum,average);
dbms_output.put_line('Sum: '||totsum||' Average: '||average);
end;
/
```

This give the error:

```
ORA-06550: line 6, column 31:
PL/SQL: ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here
ORA-06550: line 6, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
4.     procedure sumavg(x out number, y out number) is
5.     begin
6.     select sum(total) into x, avg(total) into y from st;
7.     end;
8.
```

I need to display values totsum and average. Please help with a corrected code. Thank you.

Comment: `select sum(total) into x, avg(total) into y from st;` should be `select sum(total) avg(total) into x,y from st;` please read the manual.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you. so the syntax is select <value1>,<value2>,... into <variable1>,<variable2> from <table>

Comment: @a_horse... A comma is still missing in your statement.

Answer (score 1):

At line 6, the `select..into` should be :

`select sum(total), avg(total) into x,y from st;`